# How to remove/change decimal sum value in flextable

Tags: r, sum, flextable

I managed to create a flextable based on the below code.
The data that is being used in opleiding1 through 4 looks a bit like this: 0, 0, 1, 7, 3, 7, 0

```
t7 <- data.frame(df$opleiding.1.[df$startvraag=="Ja"],
                 df$opleiding.2.[df$startvraag=="Ja"],
                 df$opleiding.3.[df$startvraag=="Ja"],
                 df$opleiding.4.[df$startvraag=="Ja"]
)

t7 <- data.frame(aantal=(apply(t7, 2, sum))) %>% round(digits = 0)
rownames(t7) <- c("hbo, universitair", "mbo, vwo, havo", "vmbo/mavo", "onbekend")
t7
```

Creating a flextable with the following code:

```
t7 <- xtable(t7)

ft7 <- t7 %>% xtable_to_flextable() %>% 
  fontsize(part = "header", size = 20) %>%
  fontsize(part = "body", size = 18) %>%
  align_text_col(align = "left") %>% 
  align_nottext_col(align = "center") %>%
  width(width = 2.3) %>%
  width(j = 1, width = 2.0) %>%
  height_all(height = .5) %>%
  border_inner(border = std_border) %>% 
  font(fontname = "Open Sans") %>%
  color(part = "header", color = d) %>% 
ft7
```

This gives me a flextable which is just as I want it except for the decimal which are shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PPgH.jpg). I've looked for possible solutions but nothing seems to work. It looks like the decimal is added when converting the table to an flextable. When I run the previous code (mentions on top) it does not return with any decimals as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5OeW.jpg). Hope someone can help me sort this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is because your `aantal` column's type is *double*, meaning it is holding *real*  values. You can change it's type to *integer* as you create the data.frame.

Try this

```r
t7 <- data.frame(aantal=(apply(t7, 2, sum))) %>% 
    round(digits = 0) %>%
    mutate(aantal = as.integer(aantal))
```

Comment: The original dataset had NA, - and nvt in it. After filtering this out I changed the type of data to numeric with the following code: df$opleiding.4.[is.na(df$opleiding.4.)] <- 0
df$opleiding.4. <- as.numeric(df$opleiding.4.). So the type was set to numeric. Is there a reason of what you know of why numeric shows a decimal and integer does not, while using the round function? Just for my understanding tho. And thanks for your solution!